# textViewDidChange method is not being called when the UITextView.text property is being updated?

Tags: ios, swift

In the Master Detail template with CoreData, I'm saving 'String' shortcuts to my UITableView. I select a cell and place my shortcut value into the UITextView. When the configureView method is invoked, the textViewDidChange method is not being called; thus not updating my UITextView content properly. Is the UITextView not being updated even though I'm adding a shortcut to it? Is there a more proper way of updating my UITextView with items from the UITableView?

```
var detailItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {

    if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {

        if let text = self.textView {

            var shortCut = detail.valueForKey("shortCut")!.description + " "
            var currentValue = textData + shortCut
            text.insertText(String(currentValue))

            // textData is a constantly updated variable with the textView's text property value...

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the delegate of `self.textview` to `self` using:

`self.textview.delegate = self`